# Counting kth power residues mod $p^a$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations

I want to understand how to count power residue modulo a fixed integer. More precisely I would like to count the residues of the form $x^k$ in the group of units of $Z/p^a Z$. I am told that it is
$$\phi(p^a) /(k, \phi(p^a))$$

for most of the cases of a and p, but I do not understand how it is so. Has the Chinese remainder theorem have something to do rewriring this questions in a more handball way?

Comment: The Chinese Remainder theorem doesn't help (you don't have coprime numbers here), nor does handball (though I never tried that strategy myself). Also, your formula does not include a $k$, which makes it very unlikely to hold.

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: @darijgrinberg I edited what I have read as being true, thanks!

Comment: Good step forward. I'd like to second the "What have you tried?" question, as well as ask you to be more precise about what you mean by "most of the cases" (mayhaps you want $p$ to be odd?).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1:** Use the fact that if $p$ is odd then $(\Bbb{Z}/p^a\Bbb{Z})^{\times}$ is cyclic of order $\phi(p^a)$, and if $p=2$ is even and $a>1$ then
$$(\Bbb{Z}/p^a\Bbb{Z})^{\times}\cong(\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z})\times(\Bbb{Z}/2^{a-1}\Bbb{Z}).$$

**Hint 2:** In a cyclic group of order $n$, every element is a $k$-th power if $\gcd(k,n)=1$. If $k\mid n$ then the $k$-th powers are precisely the elements of orderd dividing $\tfrac{k}{n}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Say $p$ is odd, so that the multiplicative group of units is cyclic of order $n=\phi(p^a)$. Let $x$ be a generator of this subgroup. I know that the order of $x^k$ is $n/(k,n)$, and am willing to use this fact. Can I use that the set of $k$-th powers is a subgroup, therefore cyclic, and taking a generator we see that its order it also $n/(k,n)$, giving the number of $k$-th powers? Is that related to your second hint? For the case $p=2$, is it by the fact that $k$-th powers in a product of groups are pairs of $k$-th powers? (Sorry, I am really discovering groups...)

Comment: @TheStudent You are entirely correct on all points.